Homomorphism from field of hyperreals to field of reals?
I am curious if it is possible to construct a homomorphism from a field of hyperreal numbers to the field of real numbers?  (Similarly, a homomorphism from the surreals to the reals?)
Assuming that the elements of the hyperreal field are finite reals (r), infinitesimals (ε), and infinite numbers (ω), how would the homomorphism be defined?
I imagine that each monad of a given real number in the hyperreal field could be mapped to the same real number of the real field.  However, how would each infinite number (ω) of the hyperreal field be mapped to the real field?  Can the infinite elements be mapped to an element named "undefined"?  I realize that doesn't make much sense, since "undefined" is not an element of the real field.
So, is there no such homomorphism?

There's no field homomorphism from any hyperreal field to the reals because the linear order is definable in terms of the algebraic structure and any hyperreal field is non-Archimedean.

Every homomorphism of fields is injective, hence you cannot map the whole monad to a single element.

@JamesEHanson, thank you for your reply.  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  I hear you saying two different things:  1) "the linear order is definable in terms of the algebraic structure," and 2) "any hyperreal field is non-Arch."  Are you saying it's simply not possible to define a homomorphism from a non-Arch field to an Arch field?  I'm not sure how that is related to linear order.  So far as I know, both the reals and hyperreals have a linear order.  Please clarify.  :)

There can be no ring homomorphism from an Archimedean real-closed field to a non-Archimedean real-closed field. It's not clear to me though that this is what you're asking for in your question.

@EmilJeřábek, thank you for this insight.  I was laboring under the impression that a homomorphism could map many elements in the domain to a single element in the codomain.  But I see what you're saying about how a Field cannot support a non-injective homomorphism, even though a ring or group could.   Follow up question:  if there is no homomorphism between the hyperreal field and the real field, then what is the relationship?  Is the real field simply a subfield of the hyperreal field?

@JamesEHanson, thank you, this is helpful.  Yes, I'm wondering if there is a homormorphism from a hyperreal field to the real field, in particular, but I like how you made the question more general, saying you cannot have a homomorphism from a non-arch field to an arch field.  So, why is that?  Is it because the hyperreal field has elements that the real field does not have, which means there is no injection from one to the other?

I believe that in order for this question to be clear, the OP should provide the exact definition of "hyperreals" that is being used in the question.

So first of all, this is a really common implicit misconception, but there is no 'the' hyperreal field. Hyperreal fields (and their surrounding non-standard model of some part of set theory) are usually built with an ultrapower construction, which will in general depend on a choice of ultrafilter. There are 'choice-free' constructions (in the sense of arbitrary choices, not the axiom of choice) of hyperreal fields, such as this one due to Kanovei and Shelah and these can actually be used to build examples that are uniquely specified up to (non-unique) isomorphism, but in applications it doesn't really matter that much which one is used.

There is no field homomorphism from any hyperreal field to $\mathbb{R}$. This is because $^\ast \mathbb{R}$ is a real-closed field, so the relation $\varphi(x,y) = \exists z (x + z^2 = y)$ defines a non-strict linear order making it into an ordered field. Since field homorphisms are always injective and isomorphisms onto their image, this implies that any field homomorphism between real-closed fields preserves this order relation. So a field homomorphism $f : {^\ast\mathbb{R}} \to \mathbb{R}$ would need to map a positive infinite element $\omega$ to some positive $x$, but then $x < n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we have that $n < \omega$ in $^\ast \mathbb{R}$ but $f(n) = n > f(\omega)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, which is a contradiction.
I would argue that the only 'natural' map from $^\ast\mathbb{R}$ to (almost) $\mathbb{R}$ is the standard part map (which actually maps to the extended reals, of course), but the only structure this really preserves is the order and the specific values of rational numbers.
There can, however, be a field isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $^\ast \mathbb{C}$, but this will be highly non-canonical and not terribly useful in the context of non-standard analysis since it will have almost no compatibility with the ambient non-standard structure around $^\ast \mathbb{C}$.

James, thank you for further clarification. In my first sentence of my post, I was actually trying (though apparently not hard enough) to pose my question by referring to "a hyperreal field" rather than "the" hyperreal field.  However, I see now that later in my paragraphs I refer to "the hyperreal field" by which I meant, "the hyperreal field in question, whatever it is."  I will be more careful in the future.  I appreciate your comment about the standard part being an (almost) mapping from *R to R; that makes sense.  I'll take a look at Kanovi and Shelah!  Thank you!!

@euclidub Oh sorry, I missed that you had said "a hyperreal field" at first. I feel like that has more to do with my reading comprehension than with you not being clear enough.

James, you are too kind.  Looking back, the title of my post does not make it clear, and my second two paragraphs say "the."  Alas, I'm learning.  :)
